# How to use coc-jedi to help coc-pyright jump to pytest fixture definitions?

Tags: plugin-coc, plugin-jedi-vim, pyright

I really enjoy `coc-pyright` and use it all the time for everything. But it can't jump to Pytest fixture definitions, and [there are no plans to include such a feature](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/1702#issuecomment-810652311).

> Pyright doesn't include any knowledge of third-party libraries beyond what is provided to it in type stubs or type annotations, and we don't have any plans to add hard-coded logic that is library-specific.

My vscode-using friends can jump to fixture definitions (including fixtures created in `conftest.py`) because the feature has been built into Pylance for some years now.

The Jedi language server (and by extension `coc-jedi`) *can* do this but, from what little I've seen, is less featureful than `coc-pyright` in every other respect.

Installing both is not supported (`coc-jedi` say not to install it at the same time as `coc-python` which has been superceded by `coc-pyright`)

Is there a way I can install `coc-jedi` but *only* use it for `<Plug>(coc-definition)` and keep using `coc-pyright` for everything else?

Here's a snippet to demonstrate Pytest fixtures, and a gif showing how `coc-defintion` works with `coc-jedi`:

```python
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    pass


def test_my_test(my_fixture):
    pass
```

[image: Using Jedi to jump to Pytest definition]

Comment: Use the plugin's support channels.

Comment: I've created an issue at `coc-jedi`: https://github.com/pappasam/coc-jedi/issues/61

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer I suspect the difference between coc-pyright and coc-jedi is not that pyright vs. jedi but the way they handle failure. I suspect coc-jedi to rely on a fall back. I'll be glad if you could confirm my understanding in your test. When I'll have the time I'll have a look at the code of coc-jedi to confirm my hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

I made some test with Jedi itself and some other LSP integration ([jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim)) and it seems to me that Jedi itself don't find the implementation itself.

I suspect that [coc-jedi](https://github.com/pappasam/coc-jedi) as a fall back when Jedi doesn't find the implementation and I suspect that the fall back is `[`<kbd>Ctrl i</kbd> (a.k.a.: `[<C-i>`).

[:help [_CTRL-i](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#%5B_CTRL-I)

```
[ CTRL-I    Jump to the first line that contains the keyword
            under the cursor.  The search starts at the beginning
            of the file.  Lines that look like a comment are
            ignored (see 'comments' option).  If a count is given,
            the count'th matching line is jumped to, and comment
            lines are not ignored.
```

A way to implement this fallback in general for coc.nvim is the following:

```
" nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)

nmap <silent><expr> gd GoToDef()

function! DelayedGotoDef(timer)
  if g:start_curpos == getcurpos()
    execute "normal! [\<C-i>"
  endif
endfunction

function! GoToDef()
  let g:start_curpos = getcurpos()
  call timer_start(200, 'DelayedGotoDef', {'repeat' : 1})
  return "\<Plug>(coc-definition)"
endfunction
```

We replace the proposed mapping:

```
" nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
```

By another mapping that tries the same operation but if it doesn't move the cursor within 200 ms then it perform the fallback operation (`[<C-i>` in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think Jedi [genuinely does support Pytest fixtures](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/791).